# Database records delete as soon as debugging is stopped

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

When I enter the fields it works and sends the records to the database and if I clear the form and enter another it also sends that one to the database but when I stop debugging, the database is empty.

Is there something wrong with my code?

What should I do to resolve this issue?

• I am using VB.NET with a Microsoft Access database

• There are two pages of code: *Control* and *Create Account Form*

*Control*

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class DBControl
    'CREATE YOUR DB CONNECTION
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                         "Data Source=Hotel.mdb;")
    'PREPARE DB COMMAND
    Private DBCmd As OleDbCommand

    'DB DATA
    Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    'QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

    'QUERY STATISTICS
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        'RESET QUERY STATS
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try
            'OPEN A CONNECTION
            DBCon.Open()

            'CREATE DB COMMAND
            DBCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBCon)

            'LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

            'CLEAR PARAMS LIST
            Params.Clear()

            'EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATABASE
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = ex.Message
        End Try

        'CLOSE YOUR CONNECTION
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    End Sub

    'INCLUDE QUERY & COMMAND PARAMETERS
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
End Class
```

*Create Account Form*

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Create
    Private Access As New DBControl
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                       "Data Source=Hotel.mdb")

    Private Sub Create_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then DBCon.Open() : Exit Sub
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
        AddUser()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        txtForename.Clear()
        txtSurname.Clear()
        txtNumber.Clear()
        txtEmail.Clear()
        txtPass.Clear()
        txtCity.Clear()
    End Sub


    Private Sub cbxTitle_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxTitle.SelectedIndexChanged, txtFirst.TextChanged, txtSurname.TextChanged, txtEmail.TextChanged, txtPass.TextChanged
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbxTitle.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirst.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSurname.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) AndAlso txtPass.Text.Length = 8 Then
            btnCreate.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddUser()
        'ADD PARAMETERS
        Access.AddParam("@Title", cbxTitle.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Forename", txtForename.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Surname", txtSurname.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Number", txtNumber.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Email", txtEmail.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Pass", txtPass.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@City", txtCity.Text)

        'EXECUTE INSERT COMMAND
        Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO Customers([Title], [Forename], [Surname], [Number], [Email], [Pass], [City])" &
                         "VALUES(@Title, @Forename, @Surname, @Number, @Email, @Pass, @City)")

        'REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub

        DBCon.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help is appreciated

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a proper way to work with file-based databases in VB.NET.

1. Add the data file to your project in the Solution Explorer. If you're prompted to copy the file into the project, accept.
2. Set the `Copy To Output Directory` property of the data file to `Copy If Newer`.
3. Use "|DataDirectory|" to represent the folder path of the data file in your connection string, e.g. `Dim connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Hotel.mdb;"`.

Now you have two copies of your database. You have the one in the project folder, with the other source files, and the one in the output folder, with the EXE. The source file should stay clean, unsullied by test data. The copy in the output folder is the one you connect to when you debug so that's the one you need to look in to find any changes you make while  debugging/testing.

Because you set it to only copy when the source file is newer than the output file, any changes you make while testing will not be lost unless you actually make a change to the source file, e.g. add a column or a table. By default, that property is set to `Copy Always`, which means that your source file is copied over the output file every time the project is built, so any time any source file changes and you run the project again. That's why your data "disappears".